# Service objects pattern in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby

I´m trying to develop a service class that provides payment services in my Rails app, but it´s not working.

Service class (lib/paypal_service.rb) (not sure if it should be placed here, I read it in some posts):

```
class PaypalService
  attr_reader :api #, :express_checkout_response  

  def initialize()
    @api = PayPal::SDK::Merchant::API.new    
  end

  def test()
    puts "Congratulations, you have called test"
  end
end
```

Controller (uses service):

```
class BookingsController < ApplicationController
  include BoatsHelper
  require 'paypal_service'

  def create
    PaypalService.test   
  end 

...
```

In output I get:

```
 NoMethodError (private method `test' called for PaypalService:Class):
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `PaypalService.new.test` instead of `PaypalService.test` as `test` is an `instance method` of class PaypalService and not a `class method`. Update it as below:

```
class BookingsController < ApplicationController
  include BoatsHelper
  require 'paypal_service'

  def create
    PaypalService.new.test   
  end 

...
```

**NOTE:**

If you want to call it as `PaypalService.test` then you can convert `test` to a class method as follows:

```
class PaypalService
  attr_reader :api #, :express_checkout_response  

  def initialize
    @api = PayPal::SDK::Merchant::API.new    
  end

  def self.test
    puts "Congratulations, you have called test"
  end
end
```

Comment: See my comment in the post above.

Comment: Can you share the error stacktrace that you receive.

Comment: Make sure to restart the `rails server`. I just tested the code and it works both ways but I did need to restart the server.

Comment: You were right. I just needed to restart. You both guys were right.

Answer (score 3):

It's because you are calling a class method, but you have defined an instance method.

Change you controller to this

```
def create
  PaypalService.new.test   
end
```

Or define a class method and leave your controller as is

```
class PaypalService
  attr_reader :api #, :express_checkout_response  

  def initialize()
    @api = PayPal::SDK::Merchant::API.new    
  end

  def self.test
    new.test
  end

  def test()
    puts "Congratulations, you have called test"
  end
end
```

Comment: Sorry, I understand it and I see it´s simple, but I have tried both options and still getting same error. There has to be something else... I have added an small trace to initialize method and is not displayed. Could it be related with the paths? My service class is stored in lib/paypal_service.rb

Comment: It's nothing to do with paths because PaypalService is found. The class constant is loaded. Can you post more code?